# For which $a$, equation $4^x-a2^x-a+3=0$ has at least one solution.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find all values of $a$ for which the equation $4^x-a2^x-a+3=0$ has at least one solution.

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ We can write it as $$2^{x}-a-\frac{a}{2^x}+\frac{3}{2^x}=0$$

So $\displaystyle \left(2^x+\frac{3}{2^x}\right)=a\left(1+\frac{1}{2^x}\right).$

Now for the existance of solution $\displaystyle 2^x+\frac{3}{2^x}\geq 2\sqrt{3}$ Using $\bf{A.M\geq G.M}$

So $\displaystyle a\left(1+\frac{1}{2^x}\right)\geq 2\sqrt{3}\Rightarrow a\geq \sqrt{3}\cdot \frac{2^x}{2^x+1}\geq \sqrt{3}$

But answer given as $a\geq 2,$ please explain me whats wrong with that, Thanks

Comment: $\frac{2^x}{2^x+1} < 1$ and hence the inequality in the last step is not correct.

Comment: $\displaystyle a\left(1+\frac{1}{2^x}\right)\geq 2\sqrt{3}$ will give $a \geq \sqrt{3}\frac{2^{x+1}}{2^x+1}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $t = 2^x$. The equation is $t^2-at-a+3 = 0$. This quadratic should have a positive root. Hence $a^2 + 4(a-3) \geq 0$ which gives $(a+6)(a-2) \geq 0$. Thus $a \geq 2$.

Comment: Although this is correct, it doesn't explain how the alleged solution in the OP is wrong.

Comment: The problem is in the last step: $\frac{2^x}{2^x+1} \geq 1$

Comment: That's not the only problem, though. The application of AM-GM loses something too.

Comment: @T.Bongers, Yes, of course.

Comment: Thanks Muralidharan would you like to explain me $t_{1}\cdot t_{2} = 3-a>0\Rightarrow a<3$ but above you write $a\geq 2.$ Means why product is negative  for $a> 3,$ If roots are positive.

Comment: When $a=3$, one of the roots is positive and the other root is zero. When $a > 3$, one root is positive and the other root is negative and hence product of the roots is negative. When $-6 < a < 2$, it has no real roots. When $a \leq -6$ both roots are negative. Hence we can  solve for $t = 2^x$ only when $a \geq 2$.

Answer (score 3):

You found a necessary condition, but not a sufficient one. You've concluded that

$$a \ge \frac{2^x + \frac{3}{2^x}}{1 + \frac 1 {2^x}}$$

Your application of AM-GM is all about minimizing the numerator, but it doesn't minimize the **entire** fraction. In fact, AM-GM is sharp when $2^x = \sqrt{3}$, in which case the fraction is $6 / (\sqrt{3} + 1) \approx 2.2$.

---

To minimize the whole thing: Recognize that it's equivalent to

$$a \ge \frac{4^x + 3}{2^x + 1}$$

As $x \to \infty$, this blows up; as $x \to -\infty$, this tends to $3$. Standard calculus techniques (e.g. root of first derivative) shows that this is minimized when $x = 0$, and the minimum is in fact $2$. By continuity, each value of $a \ge 2$ has a corresponding $x$. Hence $a \ge 2$ is sufficient.

Comment: +1.  Or if one loses sleep without using AM-GM, above $\implies a \geqslant (2^x+1)+\dfrac4{2^x+1}-2 \geqslant 4-2 = 2$

Comment: Very Nice Macavity.